# What does Pete mean ( from “Adam-12 “) by “I checked you out in one piece, I want to check you back in the same way?

Tags: meaning

In Adam-12 S01.Ep1, there's a conversation:

Reed: You don’t have much confidence in me, do you?
Pete: **I checked you out in one piece, I want to check back you in the same way.**
Reed: It’s none of my business but there is something eating you, isn’t there?
Pete: You called it.
Reed: Yeah?
Pete: It’s none of your business.

What does **“I checked you out in one piece, I want to check you back in the same way** mean?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the show so I don't know what's going on, but if you're asking what "in one piece" means, it means "not broken" - i.e., in one piece rather than broken into many pieces.

Comment: Reed was unharmed when Pete saw him set out, and he wants him to return unharmed.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the meaning

Comment: It's terminology that would normally be applied to an item you borrow or rent, rather than to a person (although I don't know if Reed is a person).

Comment: @StuartF, traditionally yes, but using it to a person has become common. It suggests there is a risk of Reed suffering harm in whatever he is going to do.